# rails + omniauth: inspect basic info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authorization, omniauth

this is my code to get the user's basic information after authorization:

```
basic_info = request.env['omniauth.auth'].extra.raw_info

first = basic_info.first_name
last = basic_info.last_name 
email = basic_info.email 
id = basic_info.id
```

the four variables get the data, so it works.
but when I'm trying `basic_info.inspect` command, I get:

> "#"

why is that? shouldn't it dump all the values?

Comment: Have you tried `attributes` method OR `to_yaml` to see all values..??

Answer (score 1):

Like Singh suggested in his comment, you should use the `to_yaml` method to see what is inside a hash of nested hashes. I usually put the following code in the applicable controller:

```
raise request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml
```

Now when trying to login the controller just renders the yaml.

EDIT: Now that Rails 4 uses the better_errors gem, this method of inspecting the omniauth hash no longer works so well. A better way now is:

```
render :text => "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return
```